# Waypoint API params

Tags: here-api

Is there a possibility to give some more params in the waypoint API? Things like speedlimit, height, width etc. When I create a route with the waypoint API with type truck the time between the destinations is too much and with type car the time between the destinations is too little.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see in the Swagger docs (https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html), there appear to be a list of options under "Supported place options:", including:

- course
- sideOfStreetHint
- matchSideOfStreet
- nameHint
- radius
- minCourseDistance

This then is separated from the next section, waypoint options, which only supports "stopDuration"

I'd say it's only stopDuration.